# バックグラウンドプロセスが消えるわけ

Tags: bash, sh

以下のようなシェルでバックグラウンドで処理するシェルを起動させているのですが、
しばらくたつと、バックグラウンドのプロセスが消えてしまいます。

■mainシェル（corosyncから実行されます）

```
#!/bin/sh
プロセスが起動していない場合
    ★テストスクリプト開始のログ
    /スクリプトのパス/test start &
```

バックグラウンド用のシェルでは以下のように
ループのなかで計算処理⇒sleep⇒計算処理⇒…を繰り返している状態です。

■testシェル

```
引数で処理分岐
引数がstartの場合
    while :
    do
        計算処理
        ★ログ出力
        sleep処理
        /bin/sleep スリープ時間
　　　　　　※breakおよびreturnはありません。
    done
```

上記のようになっており、計算処理のログが繰り返し出力されていることを確認できています。
テストスクリプト開始のログがたまに出ており（毎回ではない）
上記のような場合、勝手に（？）プロセスが消えたりするのもなのでしょうか？
（sleepしているとnohup実行しない場合など消えたりしますか？）

説明不足で申し訳ございません。記載を追加しました。

Comment: `バックグラウンド用シェル～`というのを`hoge`とか`sample`とかサンプル的なものでいいので実行している命令を記載できますか？頭に`nohup`はつけていますか？(ターミナル切断でkillされるので)。また、1つ目のシェルスクリプトはどうやって実行していますか？

Comment: 「ループのなかで計算処理⇒sleep⇒計算処理⇒…を繰り返している」というのは確認できているのですか？　ｘｘ処理の中で breakしたりしていませんか？　　この質問のように実行されるプログラムのコードが明らかでないと、無視されても仕方ないですよ。

Comment: Siegさま　 コメントありがとうございます。nohupはつけていません。そのため、プロセスが死んだ場合は再度バックグラウンド用シェルを実行するようにしています。バックグラウンドのプロセスが、自動で消えたりするものなのでしょうか？sleepしてたりするとそういう動きになるのでしょうか？

Comment: Fumu さま　コメントありがとうございます。breakするような作りにはなっていませんでした。また、計算処理、スリープが実施されていることをログで確認しております。

Comment: corosync のログファイル(デフォルトでは `/var/log/cluster/corosync.log` )に何か手がかりがあるかもしれません。

Comment: バックグラウンドのプロセスが消えるのはどのように確認された結果でしょうか？

Comment: metropolisさま　コメントありがとうございます。確認してみます。

Comment: take88さま　コメントありがとうございます。バックグラウンドプロセス起動後にecho $! > pid_test.txtでプロセスIDをファイルに書き込んでいます。そのPIDに対して、kill -0を実施して応答有無でプロセスを確認しています。